# Mailchimp API v3 add merge field with checkboxes

Tags: mailchimp

I need to add checkboxes `merge-field` with choices to a list.

API key is valid, other requests work and I'm doing such request:

```
POST https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/424242/merge-fields

Body: {"name": "provider_accounts", "type": "checkboxes", "options": { "choices": ["BMW", "Audi", "Toyota"]}, "tag": "provider_accounts"}
```

And I got an error for some reason!

```
{
  "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
  "title": "Invalid Resource",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
  "instance": "",
  "errors": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

BTW if I change the type to `radio` request works and new `merge-field` is created.

Comment: i have exactly the same pb, its very odd